# Css rotate makes shape mover all over canvas

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to make one of the path from my svg rotate like a clock would. but the shape seems to move position when rotating rather than staying in one spot and spinning.

anyone got any advice on how to do this?

https://jsfiddle.net/vL1cdeok/13/#&togetherjs=z94iKKJQAp

```
<div class="bg">
<svg class="svg-shape" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 214.11 53.89">
            <path id="Path_1" data-name="Path 1" fill="#fff" d="M97.18,43V26.64a9.57,9.57,0,0,0-2.84-7.33,9.07,9.07,0,0,0-6.2-2.19,10.15,10.15,0,0,0-7.32,2.72,7.9,7.9,0,0,0-6.3-2.72,8.83,8.83,0,0,0-6,2.38V17.41h-7.7V43H68.7V27.69c0-3,2.11-3.52,3.17-3.52s3.18.57,3.18,3.52V43h7.89V27.69c0-3,2.11-3.52,3.17-3.52s3.18.57,3.18,3.52V43Z"/>
            <path id="Path_2" data-name="Path 2" fill="#fff" d="M119.78,43V26.4c0-6.23-4-9.28-11.4-9.28-4.38,0-6.79.81-9.43,3.43l4.9,4.85A4.93,4.93,0,0,1,108,23.69c2.74,0,3.9.85,3.9,3.19v.66h-5.24c-6.16,0-8.8,3.57-8.8,7.42a8.27,8.27,0,0,0,2.26,6,8.65,8.65,0,0,0,6.21,2.29,7.18,7.18,0,0,0,5.76-2.33V43Zm-7.89-9.61a3.3,3.3,0,0,1-.77,2.57c-.87.81-1.59,1-3.13,1-1.73,0-2.6-1-2.6-2.14s1-2.05,2.5-2.05h4Z"/>
            <path id="Path_3" data-name="Path 3" fill="#fff" d="M142.94,41.15V17.41h-7.65V19.5a7.36,7.36,0,0,0-5.77-2.38,8.48,8.48,0,0,0-6.11,2.29c-2.36,2.33-2.41,5.18-2.41,9.85s0,7.52,2.41,9.85a8.36,8.36,0,0,0,6.06,2.28,7.38,7.38,0,0,0,5.58-2.14v1.86c0,1.66-.86,3.9-4.18,3.9a5.91,5.91,0,0,1-4.43-1.62l-4.91,4.85c2.65,2.62,5.68,3.33,9.72,3.33,7.07,0,11.69-4.37,11.69-10.42m-7.89-11.9c0,2.62-.19,5.09-3.08,5.09s-3.07-2.47-3.07-5.09.19-5.09,3.07-5.09,3.08,2.48,3.08,5.09"/>
            <path id="Path_4" data-name="Path 4" fill="#fff" d="M165.25,43V9.13h-4.91V21.31a7.59,7.59,0,0,0-6.4-2.71A8.37,8.37,0,0,0,148,20.74c-2.45,2.43-2.74,6.52-2.74,10.18s.29,7.8,2.74,10.23a8.46,8.46,0,0,0,6,2.14,7.5,7.5,0,0,0,6.44-2.85V43Zm-4.91-12.09c0,4.29-.63,8-5.05,8s-5.1-3.75-5.1-8,.67-8,5.1-8,5.05,3.71,5.05,8"/>
            <path id="Path_5" data-name="Path 5" fill="#fff" d="M189.08,32.35V30.21c0-6.85-3.8-11.61-10.34-11.61-6.25,0-10.34,4.52-10.34,12.33,0,9.18,4.86,12.37,11,12.37a11.52,11.52,0,0,0,9.14-3.76l-3.13-2.9a7.32,7.32,0,0,1-5.92,2.47c-4,0-6.2-2.61-6.2-6.75ZM184.22,29h-11a7.52,7.52,0,0,1,.62-3.28,5.11,5.11,0,0,1,4.86-3.05,5,5,0,0,1,4.81,3.05,7.57,7.57,0,0,1,.68,3.28"/>
            <path id="Path_7" data-name="Path 7" fill="#fff" d="M213.59,43l-9.52-14.66,8.46-9.47h-6L197.09,30V9.13h-4.9V43h4.9V35.92l3.61-4.05L207.53,43Z"/>
            <path id="Path_8" data-name="Path 8" fill="#f17620" d="M150.94,46.44v-.6h-4.3v.6h1.82v5.61h.67V46.44Z"/>
            <path id="Path_9" data-name="Path 9" fill="#f17620" d="M155.41,52.05V49.29a1.44,1.44,0,0,0-1.31-1.58h-.25a1.51,1.51,0,0,0-1.21.52V45.84H152v6.21h.64V49.4a1,1,0,0,1,.89-1.13.61.61,0,0,1,.19,0,1,1,0,0,1,1.07.93,1.34,1.34,0,0,1,0,.2v2.65Z"/>
            <path id="Path_10" data-name="Path 10" fill="#f17620" d="M160.28,50.07v-.28c0-1.28-.66-2.08-1.78-2.08s-1.78.81-1.78,2.2.75,2.2,1.9,2.2a2,2,0,0,0,1.58-.66l-.43-.38a1.43,1.43,0,0,1-1.14.49c-.83,0-1.28-.54-1.28-1.49Zm-.64-.47h-2.29a1.94,1.94,0,0,1,.13-.71,1.1,1.1,0,0,1,1-.65,1.07,1.07,0,0,1,1,.65,1.75,1.75,0,0,1,.13.71"/>
            <path id="Path_11" data-name="Path 11" fill="#f17620" d="M164.52,48.11a1.34,1.34,0,0,0-1-.4,1.47,1.47,0,0,0-1.22.58v-.53h-.63v4.29h.63V49.42a1.06,1.06,0,0,1,1-1.15h.09a.94.94,0,0,1,.76.31Z"/>
            <path id="Path_12" data-name="Path 12" fill="#f17620" d="M171.55,52.05V49.31a1.57,1.57,0,0,0-.47-1.2,1.55,1.55,0,0,0-1.12-.4,1.7,1.7,0,0,0-1.43.71,1.42,1.42,0,0,0-1.33-.71,1.54,1.54,0,0,0-1.22.52v-.46h-.64v4.29H166V49.41a1,1,0,0,1,.88-1.14.67.67,0,0,1,.2,0,1,1,0,0,1,1.08.92,1.62,1.62,0,0,1,0,.22v2.64h.63V49.34a1,1,0,0,1,.94-1.07.38.38,0,0,1,.15,0,1,1,0,0,1,1.07.92.81.81,0,0,1,0,.22v2.64Z"/>
            <path id="Path_13" data-name="Path 13" fill="#f17620" d="M176.19,52.05V49.14c0-.93-.57-1.43-1.74-1.43a1.67,1.67,0,0,0-1.53.64l.43.39a1.14,1.14,0,0,1,1.09-.49c.8,0,1.11.32,1.11.94v.41h-1.3c-1,0-1.5.49-1.5,1.24a1.28,1.28,0,0,0,.32.88,1.58,1.58,0,0,0,1.23.39,1.56,1.56,0,0,0,1.25-.46v.41Zm-.64-1.51a1,1,0,0,1-.22.74,1.31,1.31,0,0,1-1,.29c-.69,0-1-.24-1-.74s.32-.76,1-.76h1.22Z"/>
            <path id="Path_14" data-name="Path 14" fill="#f17620" d="M179.28,52.05v-.54h-.35c-.44,0-.58-.21-.58-.63v-5h-.64v5.07a1,1,0,0,0,.9,1.14.67.67,0,0,0,.2,0Z"/>
            <path id="Path_15" data-name="Path 15" fill="#f17620" d="M186.44,50.34a1.54,1.54,0,0,0-.53-1.23,2,2,0,0,0-1.14-.43l-.69-.1a1.86,1.86,0,0,1-.85-.34.89.89,0,0,1-.28-.72c0-.69.49-1.15,1.32-1.15a2,2,0,0,1,1.47.53l.43-.42a2.5,2.5,0,0,0-1.87-.68,1.72,1.72,0,0,0-2,1.74,1.44,1.44,0,0,0,.47,1.16,2.29,2.29,0,0,0,1.16.48l.73.11a1.35,1.35,0,0,1,.82.3,1,1,0,0,1,.3.77c0,.73-.56,1.16-1.48,1.16a2.21,2.21,0,0,1-1.71-.69l-.46.45a2.71,2.71,0,0,0,2.15.82c1.31,0,2.17-.67,2.17-1.76"/>
            <path id="Path_16" data-name="Path 16" fill="#f17620" d="M190.78,47.76h-.69l-1.18,3.45-1.19-3.45H187l1.56,4.2-.3.84c-.15.39-.28.53-.72.53h-.19v.56h.27a1.22,1.22,0,0,0,.85-.3,1.32,1.32,0,0,0,.31-.51Z"/>
            <path id="Path_17" data-name="Path 17" fill="#f17620" d="M194.8,50.8c0-.8-.52-1.09-1.28-1.16l-.7-.06c-.54,0-.76-.27-.76-.63s.34-.71,1-.71a1.84,1.84,0,0,1,1.16.34l.41-.41a2.41,2.41,0,0,0-1.56-.46c-.92,0-1.6.47-1.6,1.25s.45,1.09,1.3,1.16l.72.06c.5,0,.72.25.72.63s-.44.75-1.15.75a1.78,1.78,0,0,1-1.35-.5l-.43.42a2.39,2.39,0,0,0,1.78.62c1.05,0,1.77-.48,1.77-1.31"/>
            <path id="Path_18" data-name="Path 18" fill="#f17620" d="M214.11,50.8c0-.8-.52-1.09-1.28-1.16l-.7-.06c-.55,0-.76-.27-.76-.63s.33-.71,1-.71a1.81,1.81,0,0,1,1.15.34l.42-.41a2.45,2.45,0,0,0-1.56-.46c-.93,0-1.6.47-1.6,1.25s.45,1.09,1.3,1.16l.71.06c.5,0,.72.25.72.63s-.44.75-1.15.75a1.78,1.78,0,0,1-1.35-.5l-.42.42a2.37,2.37,0,0,0,1.78.62c1,0,1.76-.48,1.76-1.31"/>
            <path id="Path_19" data-name="Path 19" fill="#f17620" d="M197.62,52.05v-.54h-.33c-.41,0-.59-.24-.59-.63V48.26h.92v-.47h-.92V46.44h-.64v1.35h-.55v.47h.55V50.9a1.06,1.06,0,0,0,1,1.15h.6Z"/>
            <path id="Path_20" data-name="Path 20" fill="#f17620" d="M202.14,50.07v-.28c0-1.28-.67-2.08-1.79-2.08s-1.78.81-1.78,2.2.75,2.2,1.9,2.2a2,2,0,0,0,1.59-.66l-.44-.38a1.4,1.4,0,0,1-1.13.49c-.83,0-1.28-.54-1.28-1.49Zm-.64-.47h-2.29a1.75,1.75,0,0,1,.13-.71,1.12,1.12,0,0,1,2,0,1.75,1.75,0,0,1,.13.71"/>
            <path id="Path_21" data-name="Path 21" fill="#f17620" d="M209.69,52.05V49.31a1.6,1.6,0,0,0-.46-1.2,1.55,1.55,0,0,0-1.12-.4,1.67,1.67,0,0,0-1.43.71,1.44,1.44,0,0,0-1.34-.71,1.54,1.54,0,0,0-1.22.52v-.46h-.64v4.29h.64V49.41a1,1,0,0,1,.89-1.14.61.61,0,0,1,.19,0,1,1,0,0,1,1.08.92,1.62,1.62,0,0,1,0,.22v2.64h.64V49.34a1,1,0,0,1,.93-1.07.38.38,0,0,1,.15,0,1,1,0,0,1,1.08.92,1.62,1.62,0,0,1,0,.22v2.64Z"/>
            <path id="Path_22" data-name="Path 22" fill="#f17620" d="M54.49,27A27.11,27.11,0,0,0,27.24,0,27.09,27.09,0,0,0,0,27,27.1,27.1,0,0,0,27.24,53.89,27.11,27.11,0,0,0,54.49,27m-5.58,0A21.67,21.67,0,0,1,5.58,27h0a21.67,21.67,0,0,1,43.33,0"/>
            <path id="Path_22-2" data-name="Path 22-2" fill="#f17620" d="M54.49,27A27.11,27.11,0,0,0,27.24,0,27.09,27.09,0,0,0,0,27,27.1,27.1,0,0,0,27.24,53.89,27.11,27.11,0,0,0,54.49,27m-5.58,0A21.67,21.67,0,0,1,5.58,27h0a21.67,21.67,0,0,1,43.33,0"/>
            <path id="Path_24" class="logo-spin" data-name="Path 24" fill="#fff" d="M44.29,37.13l-8.61-6.32,3.46,12.13-5.51-9.1-1.5,12.52-1.57-10.5-6.23,11L27,36.57l-10,7.81,6.4-8.52L11.06,39.28l9.21-5.45L7.61,32.36,18.22,30.8,7.1,24.65l10.4,2.58-7.9-9.9,8.62,6.33L14.76,11.52l5.51,9.1L21.77,8.1l1.57,10.5,6.23-11L27,17.89l10-7.81-6.4,8.52,12.27-3.42-9.2,5.45,12.66,1.48L35.68,23.65,46.8,29.81,36.39,27.23Z"/>
            <path id="Path_25" data-name="Path 25" fill="#fff" d="M97.18,43V26.64a9.57,9.57,0,0,0-2.84-7.33,9.07,9.07,0,0,0-6.2-2.19,10.15,10.15,0,0,0-7.32,2.72,7.9,7.9,0,0,0-6.3-2.72,8.83,8.83,0,0,0-6,2.38V17.41h-7.7V43H68.7V27.69c0-3,2.11-3.52,3.17-3.52s3.18.57,3.18,3.52V43h7.89V27.69c0-3,2.11-3.52,3.17-3.52s3.18.57,3.18,3.52V43Z"/>
            <path id="Path_26" data-name="Path 26" fill="#fff" d="M119.78,43V26.4c0-6.23-4-9.28-11.4-9.28-4.38,0-6.79.81-9.43,3.43l4.9,4.85A4.93,4.93,0,0,1,108,23.69c2.74,0,3.9.85,3.9,3.19v.66h-5.24c-6.16,0-8.8,3.57-8.8,7.42a8.27,8.27,0,0,0,2.26,6,8.65,8.65,0,0,0,6.21,2.29,7.18,7.18,0,0,0,5.76-2.33V43Zm-7.89-9.61a3.3,3.3,0,0,1-.77,2.57c-.87.81-1.59,1-3.13,1-1.73,0-2.6-1-2.6-2.14s1-2.05,2.5-2.05h4Z"/>
            <path id="Path_27" data-name="Path 27" fill="#fff" d="M142.94,41.15V17.41h-7.65V19.5a7.36,7.36,0,0,0-5.77-2.38,8.48,8.48,0,0,0-6.11,2.29c-2.36,2.33-2.41,5.18-2.41,9.85s0,7.52,2.41,9.85a8.36,8.36,0,0,0,6.06,2.28,7.38,7.38,0,0,0,5.58-2.14v1.86c0,1.66-.86,3.9-4.18,3.9a5.91,5.91,0,0,1-4.43-1.62l-4.91,4.85c2.65,2.62,5.68,3.33,9.72,3.33,7.07,0,11.69-4.37,11.69-10.42m-7.89-11.9c0,2.62-.19,5.09-3.08,5.09s-3.07-2.47-3.07-5.09.19-5.09,3.07-5.09,3.08,2.48,3.08,5.09"/>
            <path id="Path_28" data-name="Path 28" fill="#fff" d="M165.25,43V9.13h-4.91V21.31a7.59,7.59,0,0,0-6.4-2.71A8.37,8.37,0,0,0,148,20.74c-2.45,2.43-2.74,6.52-2.74,10.18s.29,7.8,2.74,10.23a8.46,8.46,0,0,0,6,2.14,7.5,7.5,0,0,0,6.44-2.85V43Zm-4.91-12.09c0,4.29-.63,8-5.05,8s-5.1-3.75-5.1-8,.67-8,5.1-8,5.05,3.71,5.05,8"/>
            <path id="Path_29" data-name="Path 29" fill="#fff" d="M189.08,32.35V30.21c0-6.85-3.8-11.61-10.34-11.61-6.25,0-10.34,4.52-10.34,12.33,0,9.18,4.86,12.37,11,12.37a11.52,11.52,0,0,0,9.14-3.76l-3.13-2.9a7.32,7.32,0,0,1-5.92,2.47c-4,0-6.2-2.61-6.2-6.75ZM184.22,29h-11a7.52,7.52,0,0,1,.62-3.28,5.11,5.11,0,0,1,4.86-3.05,5,5,0,0,1,4.81,3.05,7.57,7.57,0,0,1,.68,3.28"/>
          </svg>


</div>

.bg{
  background:black;
  width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
}
.svg-shape{
  width:200px;
  position:relative;
}

.logo-spin{
      position:absolute;
      top:10px;
      left:10px;
      width:10px;
      height:10px;
      transform-origin: center center;
      animation-name: spin-1;
      animation-duration: 2s;
      transition-duration: 0.8s;
      transition-property: transform;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
    
    @keyframes spin-1 {

        100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to make the following changes in your CSS. The transform-origin property was the culprit here, it was taking the center of the SVG element and not the path element. I hope it helps. I got `27px` by trial and error.

https://jsfiddle.net/wrexhg73/11/

```css
.logo-spin{
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  transform-origin: 27px 27px;
  animation: spin-1 2s linear infinite;
}
    
@keyframes spin-1 {
  from {
    transform:rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform:rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```